# Is there a way to backup a mysql database without having to run mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup

Is there a way to run a backup of a mysql database using sql? We have scripts which run updates against our databases. They only have mysql user credentials, not system login credentials.

Is there anyway to run backups of mysql via a mysql connection instead?

Comment: mysqldump itself simply connects to the server, executes SQL queries to fetch the data, and formats the output as a SQL script, ready for importing later. You can look at the nysqldump source, see the queries it executes, and write it again, except why, given that mysqldump already exists? mysqldump works with any kind of credentials, and can be used to dump only specific tables in the database that you have access to.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to run a backup of a mysql database using sql?

Short answer: No.

> ... scripts ... only have mysql user credentials, not system login credentials.

I'm pretty sure it's possible to run the **mysqldump** utility against a remote database.

However, I would have to ask "*Why?*"

Even if you *could* take a backup, what would you hope to *do* with it?

It seems to me that you don't have the tools or the credentials necessary to *take* proper backups (or to *restore* a database, which pretty much *has* to be done on the machine itself).  As such, I would guess that *someone else* is responsible for keeping these databases up and running, recoverable and well-tuned (at least I *hope* so, or your organisation is in Big Trouble).

Perhaps you should discuss options with them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
select ... into outfile
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Answer (score -3):

You can try using the built in OS backup software. Been a while, but I think I used to do it with Windows backup many years ago

Comment: I'm looking for a way to start a backup job using a sql command. I'm not sure how your answer is related to the question.

Comment: An Operating System backup is generally not suitable for backing up a running database.  
Database != File.